# Angular 8 & Cordova - ngx-youtube-player not working on Android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, youtube, angular8

I'm using Angular 8, and in order to play and control Youtube videos I'm using **ngx-youtube-player**.
On the browser everything is working fine. When building and rnning the app on Android using Cordova, the Youtube video doesn't show up. I tried to embed the video in a regular way, and it's working (I whitelisted the youtube url from the Cordova config).

This is my code: (On android the first video shows up, but second not)

```
<div class="container">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1ozGKlOzEVc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <youtube-player videoId="eXvBjCO19QY" [width]="600" [height]="600"></youtube-player>
</div>
```

When trying to debug the app I get the following error on load:

> [www.youtube.com/iframe_api:1](http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api:1) Failed to load resource:
> net::ERR_INVALID_URL

When trying to start the video from my component controls I get a refernce error of course

> ERROR ReferenceError: YT is not defined
> at t.playPauseSong (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)
> at Object.handleEvent (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)
> at Object.handleEvent (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)
> at Object.handleEvent (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)
> at Ti (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)
> at main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1
> at e.i [as _next] (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)
> at e.__tryOrUnsub (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)
> at e.next (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)
> at e._next (main.e0ff7e04d5915898ed07.js:1)

When using the developer tools on my app on Android it seems that the iframe element is missing from the  component of the ngx-youtube-player package

[Android HTML elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnqrk.png)

On the browser it looks like this:
[Browser HTML elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gox25.png)

What do I need to do in order to make the video from the **ngx-youtube-player** to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For youtube-player to work, we have to first download the iframe_api.

In the code where you're using the `youtube-player` add this code

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  const target = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'

  if (!isScriptLoaded(target)) {
    const tag = document.createElement('script')
    tag.src = target
    document.body.appendChild(tag)
  }
}

isScriptLoaded(target: string): boolean {
  return document.querySelector('script[src="' + target + '"]') ? true : false
}
```

1. I'm controlling if I already had added the script
2. If not, then add the script into the code